# about textarea \r\n or \n in python

Tags: python, textarea

i have tested code in firefox under ubuntu:

the frontend is a textarea,in textarea press the key ENTER,then submit to the server,

on the backend you'll get find \r\n string

```
r=request.POST.get("t")
r.find("\r\n")>-1:
    print "has \r\n"
```

my question is when we will get \r\n ,when we'll get \n?is this platform independent?

this is important when want to use this string to use as a regular expression,any adivse is welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, you are dealing with a platform-specific ways to encode a newline:

- In Windows platforms, a newline is typically encoded as `\r\n`
- In Linux/Unix/OS X, a newline is typically encoded as `\n`

Similarly, web browsers tend to favor these conventions: IE uses `\r\n` newlining, whereas Safari and Firefox use `\n`.

As a solution, considering using Python functions that are aware of different new line encodings, e.g. provide a universal newline support.

For instance if you want to split a string into lines, use splitlines:

```
lines = r.splitlines()
```